# Match Action Bar font and color to application

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, android-actionbar

I want to match my applications font to the font that the action bar has. I need to know what font and styling is used on the action bar. I also want to have the same exact color as well. Provided are code samples and pictures of what I mean.

[image: two muppets]

In the above image I want to match the text that says "GPATrack" to the text that says "Menu". I would also like to have the background of "Menu" to be the same color as the action bar.

Here is the XML that controls the view in the above image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="@string/menu"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:textColor="#fffeff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is just an example, not my actual application, I cut out everything that seemed to add clutter.

Comment: "I would also like to have the background of "Menu" to be the same color as the action bar" -- you are the one who chose the color of the action bar. It is in your theme. See what you chose there, then use the same color.

Comment: @CommonsWare The color was chosen by android studio when the project was created. As such I do not even know where that is. I have a feeling it's default which means that it's not even listed anywhere. How would I know the font style if it's default as well?

Comment: "The color was chosen by android studio when the project was created" -- then choose your own color, so you control the value. Use that in your theme, and also use that for your other UI element. "How would I know the font style if it's default as well?" -- there is no single "default". It varies by theme (`Theme.Holo`, `Theme.Material`, `Theme.AppCompat`, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color of actionbar, define a custom style.

```
 <resources>
 <style name="myActionTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
 </style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">YourColor</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

The text of the action bar is present in strings.XML as app name. You can edit it to your requirement.

Comment: Where can I find the different themes at? Further, where do I put them at in my project? Whenever I google I just get code fragments with no direction as to actually where to change that at.

Comment: Look into your app project structure and locate `styles.xml` under the values folder.